# PowerPivot - How to filter columns yet retain grand total

Tags: powerpivot

in the table below, I would like to graph a subset of the columns, specifically the ones highlighted in green. however, I would like to compute the percentage based upon the grand total of the whole set. filtering columns rescopes the data set and hence the denominator.

I would like to show and graph columns "4" and "Excellent value (5)" while retaining the current "Grand Total." for the ct row, for example, the value would be 8/14 for column "4", and likewise for other cells.

as a candidate solution, I created a secondary table which references the table shown below. is this the cleanest way to accomplish the goal? it seems a bit kludgey and rather time consuming.

ultimately this graph will be rendered in sharepoint so it needs the dynamic interaction with the ssas data. I am assuming that this will be the case since my derived table is using the GetPivotData function which the parent table uses.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an ALL() to open out the filter context which in turn means that it doesn't matter which columns are selected.

Assuming you have a table called 'table' and a column called 'response_id' you could use something like:

```
= SUM(COUNTROWS(table)) / 
      CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(table), ALL('table'[response_id]))
```

If your real life problem is more complex then you might need to adjust the ALL() to include other columns or look at ALLEXCEPT() to do the opposite.

Comment: unfortunately I am new to pivot tables. I went back to my tabular project to add the denominator you provided as a measure thinking that if I added it to the values box, it would always calculate the total for all columns, but it still scopes to the selected columns. is this formula a measure or calculated column to be added to the visual studio tabular model, or added somewhere in excel such as powerpivot manage data model? it seems promising so I will continue to tinker with it. thanks.

Comment: it took me a while to wrap my head around pivot table calculated fields and dax, but your answer got me on the right path, although I had to adapt it more extensively to my scenario by ALLing a different table....

I ended up creating a measure in my tabular project because I don't think that excel allows adding a calculated field (measure) to cube data.

thank you for the help!